# Running two batch labels (:label) at the same time

Tags: batch-file, user-input

I am currently making a game in batch for fun, and I have everything done besides the input. So far, for the input, I have this code:

```
:input
        rem Read player input
        set "key="
        for /f "delims=" %%K in ('xcopy /W "%~F0" "%~F0" 2^>nul') do if not defined key set "key=%%K"
        if "!key:~-1!" equ "!CR!" goto endInput
        if "!key:~-1!" equ "!BS!" (
            if defined input set "input=%input:~0,-1%"
        ) else (
            set "input=%input%!key:~-1!"
        )
        set /p "=%input%" > input.txt < nul


        if not exist input.txt goto error
        cls
        if exist input.txt (
        for /f "delims=" %%x in (input.txt) do set "inp=%%x"
        set "dir=!input:~-1!"
        ) else goto error
goto input
```

I want this to retrieve user input while running the other section of the program above it. (I know, it uses a external input file, but it's pretty fast.)

Comment: I don't think this is possible; however, you could put the other code into a separate batch file and run it using the `start` command (with no `/WAIT` switch) -- just as an idea...

Comment: @aschipfl I can't use this, as it makes it a lot slower. However, I do know that this is possible to do.

Comment: No. Despite what you think you know, it is not possible for a single batch process to do parallel processing. Aschipfl is mostly correct - The only option is to have multiple batch processes running, with communication between them handled by temporary files. This is how I handled user input with my [SNAKE.BAT game](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4741). Both processes can be embedded within a single script, but the script must be run separately for each process, Both batch script processes can run within the same console window.

Comment: @dbenham I understand what you are saying, but I don't know how to do that. Could you please show me how?